# constexpression subscript operator of STL containers

Tags: c++, stl, constexpr, c++14

```
constexpr const_reference at( size_type pos ) const;
```

How can this overload of STL container accessors work with non-constexpr parameters? What are classical use cases of this overload?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such thing as `constexpr` parameters in a function declaration. A `constexpr` function call can only be evaluated at compile time if and only if all parameters involved in that function call are constant expressions.

That being said, the only case where a `constexpr` function must be evaluated at compile time is when it is used to calculate a template parameter.

At least one use case for the example you give, is for [`std::array::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at).

Comment: A really neat fearure is that the compiler is required to complain that the element is out of bounds if `std::array<T,N>::at` is evaluated in a `constexpr` context, as the `throw` that `at` does is not `constexpr`.

Answer (score 7):

> How can this overload of STL container accessors work with non-constexpr parameters?

Declaring a function `constexpr` means that if its called with constant expressions for all its arguments, then the result is also a constant expression.

It can still be called with non-constant arguments; you just can't use the result as a constant expression.

> What are classical use cases of this overload?

Getting a compile-time constant out of a suitable container, for example:

```
constexpr std::array<int,5> values {{2,3,5,7,11}};

template <int n> void do_stuff();  // needs a compile-time constant
do_stuff<values.at(3)>();          // provide a compile-time constant
```